# How can I see all ANSI symbols in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, symbols, ansi

I need see all ANSI symbols in Notepad++ to create formulas, expressions and equations math in Notepad++.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your encoding is set as `Encode in UTF-8`.

[image: IMG:]